# How to call game Object instance methods when held in a LinkedList<Entity> container?

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning to code a Pong game in Java. My game's visible objects are held in a container as such:

```
LinkedList<Entity> gameObject = new LinkedList<Entity>();
```

I iterate through the container and call each instance's update() and render() function.

```
public class ObjectHandler {

public void render(GraphicsContext g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.gameObject.size(); i++) {
        Entity tempObject = this.gameObject.get(i);
        tempObject.render(g);
    }

    ...

}
```

However if on collision I need to call ball.flipXY(),  how do I directly access this particular instance within the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you asking, but the variable `tempObject` is actually an instance of the container currently being iterated. The variable changes whenever the `for` block ends.

However, I would use `forEach` iterator instead, as index seems not to be required in that particular case.

```
for (Entity entity : gameObject) {
   // now entity is current instance being iterated, equals to gameObject.get(i)
   entity.render(g);
   if ( something ) entity.flipXY();
} // if algoritm reaches this point, entity is changed to next element of the container
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are filling the container, in case of ball object, you can fix its position within container with a strategy. For example, I assume if ball should be always there in container make sure index zero is reserved for your ball object. So you can retrieve it whenever you need. Or if ball is not always available add the ball object as the last object within your container, so you can extract it whenever you need as per availability.